# Using javascript to add an image to a list and then deleting that list item when the image is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Firstly I know I can make things  a lot easier by creating the ul in HTML. I'm not supposed to be doing that.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body id="body">
    <form  id="form" >
      <input id="userInput" placeholder="Enter your list item here">
      <button type="button"  onclick="inputFunction()">Add</button>
    </form>
    <script src="A4.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My Javascript so far:

```
// Creating Array
var listData = ["Crab","Lobster","Scallops"];
// Creating initial List
function listFunction(){
  var ul = document.createElement("ul");
  ul.id = 'ulId';

  document.getElementById('body').appendChild(ul);
  listData.forEach(liFunction);

  function liFunction(element){
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML+=element;
  }
}
listFunction();

// Adding user input to the list
function inputFunction() {
  var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  listData.push(input);
  var newLi = document.createElement("li");
  document.getElementById('ulId').appendChild(newLi);
  newLi.innerHTML=input;
}



var liImg = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < liImg.length; i++) {
  liImg[i].addEventListener('mouseover', handlerFunction, false);
}


function handlerFunction(e) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.setAttribute("src","https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/nuove/128x128/actions/fileclose.png");
  img.setAttribute("height","10");
  img.setAttribute("width", "10");
  document.getElementsByTagName('li').innerHTML += "img";
}
```

So what I'm supposed to be doing is first create a list using the listData array, and displaying it on the page. Then I take the user input and add it to the list. This part is working fine

The part I am stuck on is having to create/display an image next to each list item when it is mouseover'ed. Then having to delete that specific list item if the image is clicked. I've created the eventListener, but the img part doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

`img` is not string, it is a variable, so remove the surrounding double quotes from that. Since *img* is a node element, instead of using `innerHTML` you should use `appendChild()`. You also should use the e.target to refer the specific li element:

Change:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('li').innerHTML += "img";
```

To

```
e.target.appendChild(img);
```

I will suggest you to use `mouseenter` instead of `mousemove`. I think you need to attach the `mouseleave` event as well. You also have to attach the events to the newly created *li* elements.

Try the following way:

```js
// Creating Array
var listData = ["Crab","Lobster","Scallops"];
// Creating initial List
function listFunction(){
  var ul = document.createElement("ul");
  ul.id = 'ulId';

  document.getElementById('body').appendChild(ul);
  listData.forEach(liFunction);

  function liFunction(element){
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML+=element;
  }
}
listFunction();

// Adding user input to the list
function inputFunction() {
  var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  listData.push(input);
  var newLi = document.createElement("li");
  newLi.addEventListener('mouseenter', handlerFunction, false);
  newLi.addEventListener('mouseleave', removeImage, false);
  document.getElementById('ulId').appendChild(newLi);
  newLi.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', input);
}



var liImg = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (let i = 0; i < liImg.length; i++) {
  liImg[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', handlerFunction, false);
  liImg[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', removeImage, false);
}


function handlerFunction(e) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.setAttribute("src","https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/nuove/128x128/actions/fileclose.png");
  img.setAttribute("height","30");
  img.setAttribute("width", "30");
  img.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.closest('li').remove();
  });
  e.target.appendChild(img);
}
function removeImage(e){
  e.target.querySelector('img').remove();
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <form  id="form" >
    <input id="userInput" placeholder="Enter your list item here">
    <button type="button"  onclick="inputFunction()">Add</button>
  </form>
  <script src="A4.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you're appending the image to the `li` element.

Solution:

```
e.target.appendChild(img);
```

```js
// Creating Array
var listData = ["Crab", "Lobster", "Scallops"];
// Creating initial List
function listFunction() {
  var ul = document.createElement("ul");
  ul.id = 'ulId';

  document.getElementById('body').appendChild(ul);
  listData.forEach(liFunction);

  function liFunction(element) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML += element;
  }
}
listFunction();

// Adding user input to the list
function inputFunction() {
  var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  listData.push(input);
  var newLi = document.createElement("li");
  document.getElementById('ulId').appendChild(newLi);
  newLi.innerHTML = input;
}



var liImg = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < liImg.length; i++) {
  liImg[i].addEventListener('mouseover', handlerFunction);
}


function handlerFunction(e) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.setAttribute("src", "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/nuove/128x128/actions/fileclose.png");
  img.setAttribute("height", "10");
  img.setAttribute("width", "10");
  e.target.appendChild(img);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body id="body">
  <form id="form">
    <input id="userInput" placeholder="Enter your list item here">
    <button type="button" onclick="inputFunction()">Add</button>
  </form>
  <script src="A4.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps!